# Get the latest inserted PK after submitting a linq insert stored procedure

Tags: linq

I have a stored procedure that updates a table using linq, eg: (this is just example code by way)

```
using (DataContext db = new DataContext())
{
    d.sp_Insert_Client( textboxName.Text, textBoxSurname.Text);
}
```

What I would like to know is how to retrieve (if possible) newly generated primary key of the above inserted row, as I need this primary key as a foreign key to complete another insert.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to modify your stored procedure to return that value from database and then regenerate your Linq mapping to update that change in your ORM files. After that your `sp_Insert_Client` method will return an integer.

The other way to do that is to add another parameter into the query and mark it as output one.

To get last inserted I'd inside your SP use `SCOPE_IDENTITY`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ms190315.aspx

Comment: Hi there Marcin - I check our database and found that our actual SP does return  a result value of the primary key. So my problem has been resolved that you very myuch for your comments and help :D

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to retrieve value by using the output parameter that you can check over here : [Handling stored procedure output parameters](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/08/16/linq-to-sql-part-6-retrieving-data-using-stored-procedures.aspx) A Scott Gu post which explain that easily

Procedure

[image]

For you

```
create procdeudre nameofprocedure 
    @id int output
as
begin 
    insert in your table statement

    --retrieve identity value
    select @id = scope_identity();
end
```

Code

[image]

Comment: @sehe - i think its proper info just need go throught aritcle and need to change the procedure and have to return primarykey as output variable and that will do the task..

Comment: @sehe - i wrote proceudre and going to write code but just want to say one thing if i give a adjust code he want that what is sense in that.. he is not going to learn by him self if think its better to show the way of doing the task rather than providing code he want i hope you got my point...

Comment: Have you been far even as decided to use even go want to do look more like? [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XuQ7DehE9bw)

Comment: Hi there Pranay - thank you for the response and advise the problem has been resolved :D